# geom_line use several lines on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am currently trying to do a line plot, representing the evolution over 3 years of the number of doctors in various type of operations (one line for each), and my dataframe looks like follows :

```
type of operation     number of doctors        year

ambulatoire             12                     2019
externe                 150                    2019
ambulatoire             19                     2020
externe                 3                      2020
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work... could anyone help ?

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = df$year, y = df$"number of doctors", color = df$"type of operation"))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Do you get an error? If I run the  code I see a plot. Though have you looked at any ggplot tutorials? It's not a good idea to use `df$` inside of `aes()` in general, though technically this should work even if it is a bad practice.

Comment: well, i see a plot, but none of the lines appear...

Comment: Well something should be appearing. So maybe there’s something missing with what you’ve shared. Please include `dput(df)` in your question so we can see how your data is actually stored in R. There’s likely a problem there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
library(ggplot2)

df <-
  data.frame(
    type_of_operation = c("ambulatoire", "externe"),
    number_of_doctors = c(12, 150, 19, 3),
    year = c(2019, 2019, 2020, 2020)
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = number_of_doctors, color=type_of_operation)) +
  geom_line()
```

PS : if you want to keep space in your variables name, use this quote : ` instead of "

Comment: i tried, it does not work unfortunately... but thanks for trying

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   ggplot(df) +
      geom_line(aes(x = year,
                    y = `number of doctors`, 
                    color = `type of operation`))
```

Comment: neither does this work unfortunately...